# Regex special character '{' matches in JS but not in Java

Tags: javascript, java, regex

**test string:** `abc{123`

**regex:** `\w+{\d+`

This matches in JS, but when I try to match it in Java it gives me this error:

**Illegal repetition near index 2
`\w+{\d+`**

It works in Java only when I escape the **{** character like this: **`\w+\{\d+`**

I tried it on these two links:

- JS Link : http://myregexp.com/index.html
- Java Link:http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/

**Desired result:** If it matches in JS, it should match in Java also.

What is the difference between the regex implementation in Java and JS? How can I make it behave in the same way in Java and in JS?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it behave in the same way in Java and in JS?

You already know the answer:

> It works in Java only when I escape the { character like this: `\w+\{\d+`".

Why? Because JavaScript here is a bit more permissive. Note that in JavaScript `\w{3` will match `"f{3"`, but not `"f77"`; `\w{3}` will match `"f77"`  but not `"f{3}"`. That is to say, the same character `{` changes meaning based on whether or not somewhere later in the string an `}` appears. The behaviour is thus made more unpredictable by its permissiveness, and Java just does not allow you to write regular expressions so sloppily.

Comment: so my question was why don't we need to escape the `{` in JS

Comment: I just said, because JS permits you to be sloppy. If the question is "why does JS permit you to be sloppy" - because that's how it was made. Why do you need to peel an orange but not an apple? It is just how oranges and apples are, just enjoy each for their unique taste.

Comment: But then why it is not same with **[**. JS doesn't match it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the `{`. So the regex should look like this:

```
\w+\{\d+
```

Your initial regex isn't valid.. Javascript is just more forgiving in this case.. But `{` is one of the characters you want to escape in regex since it means *how many times to repeat* a specific character(s) like so: `[a-z]{22}` would match 22 sequential characters from a-z..

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape special characters and since a backslash is also a special character, you have to escape it as well. the regex will look like this in java: `\\w+\\{\\d+`. if you have problems, feel free to ask. you can generate a code in several programming languages here: https://regex101.com/r/D4yz40/1 this example matches your string. you can then generate the code for java and js